# Set HTML table, even col width 2X of even rows

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need relative solution for setting odd cols width as 1X and even row 2X of odd rows.
I am using this CSS:

```
.colTest{
    width:100%;
}
.colTest col:nth-child(2n+1){
    width: 100px;
}
.colTest col:nth-child(2n){
    width: 200px;
}
```

as in:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Gkxc/)

How can I set relative value (i.e %) for table cols with different number of cols?
(means that table cols are variable between 2 and 10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/2Gkxc/2/)

```
.colTest {width:100%}
.colTest col:nth-child(2n+1){
    width: 1%;
}
.colTest col:nth-child(2n){
    width: 2%;
}
```

**Update:**

Like [cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) said you'll get better result with `td` instead of `col`s, but the general idea of  my solution is the same.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/2Gkxc/4/)

```
.colTest {width:100%}
.colTest td:nth-child(2n+1){
    width: 1%;
}
.colTest td:nth-child(2n){
    width: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Formatting table cells via `cols` should work in theory, but browsers don’t always respect that. Format the `td` instead, see http://jsfiddle.net/2Gkxc/3/

```
td:nth-child(2n+1){
    width: 100px;
}
td:nth-child(2n){
    width: 200px;
}
```